# При установке gulp-clean-css удаляется файл fs-write-stream-atomic

Tags: node.js, gulp, npm

UPD-15-01-2018
Выполняю установку `gulp`

```
npm clean cache
npm -v
npm i npm check updates -g
npm i npm check updates
npm i -g gulp
npm install gulp-sass --save-dev
gulp
```

При запуске `gulp` выдаёт ошибку отсутствия `gulp-clean-css`

Запускаю команду `npm install gulp-clean-css --save-dev`

При установке `gulp-clean-css`,происходит следующее

```
C:\Open\OSPanel\domains\Compulink>npm install gulp-clean-css --save-dev
npm WARN opencart-project@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! path C:\Open\OSPanel\domains\Compulink\node_modules\npm-check-updates\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fs-write-stream-atomic
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Open\OSPanel\domains\Compulink\node_modules\npm-check-updates\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fs-write-stream-atomic' -> 'C:\Open\OSPanel\domains\Compulink\node_modules\npm-check-updates\node_modules\npm\node_modules\.fs-write-stream-atomic.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

Я посмотрел в папку данного пути и действительно папки `fs-write-stream-atomic` нет. Копирую из другой папки его и запускаю инсталляцию по новой но эта папка сама удаляется,и в итоге снова получается эта ошибка.

`npm update`,`npm-check-updates` не помогают они все останавливаются из за этой ошибки.А стоит её скопировать и повторно запустить установку,то она даже при этих командах удаляется и опять же ошибка.

Comment: Задача принципиальная? Или почему бы не попробовать установить пакеты скажем с помощью yarn?

Comment: к сожалению тут требуется только gulp,другим пользоваться не разрешено.

Comment: не, yarn - аналог npm'a, а не gulp'а, уже пару раз бывало, что в npm что-то с пакетами не так, а yarn норм зависимости подключает, по сути он так же пользуется npm, но в нем что-то работает лучше xDD

Comment: @beginner вы используете VS Code?

Comment: @St1myL нет не используется.

Comment: @beginner а можно увидеть ваш package.json?

Comment: Бьюсь об заклад на линуксе все будет работать